# Displaying Large Image in Android

Tags: android, html, image, android-studio, pan

I am trying to display a large image 4kpx by 4kpx roughly. I want to allow the user to scroll, and use pinch to zoom. I have currently tried the method of:

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\"map.png\"/></body>";
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

It seems that this is extremely resource intesive, as I get the message:

> I/v_gralloc: Self allocation

I would also like to scroll to coordinates on the map for points of interest. However using the command

```
    webview.setScrollX(10000);
    webview.setScrollY(4000);
```

Does not seem to remain the same between devices. One device may go to the right corner while the other remains in the middle. What would be the best implementation? I would prefer to steer away from libraries and breaking the picture up but I have no qualms with a good library. I just need to be usable in a commercial application.

Thank you all!

Comment: What's wrong with libraries in commercial projects?

Comment: I didn't mean that there was anything wrong with libraries, just libraries that require I make the application open source or pay a fee I would like to stay away from. I edited to further denote this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

First, Add `com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.4.1`
Second, instead of WebView, use it's custom ImageView:

```
<com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Lastly, use setImage(ImageSource) method :

```
  SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);
imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.monkey));
// ... or ...
imageView.setImage(ImageSource.asset("map.png"))
// ... or ...
imageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri("/sdcard/DCIM/DSCM00123.JPG"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll toy around with it and see if this works!